# Paste conditional formatting when conditional formatting formula is absolute

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, I have data in cells A1:I1. I have a checkbox in cell J1 which, when checked, highlights cells A1-I1 (I'm using the conditional formatting formula =$J$1=TRUE applied to range A1:I1).

I tried removing the $ sign from the formula, but then only cell A1 gets highlighted when the checkbox is checked. But with the $ in the formula, I can't paste the conditional formatting so that the J2 checkbox highlights A2:I2, J3 does A3:I3 and so on. I have 1000 columns I would like to apply this pattern so. Is there any way to quickly replicate this formatting across the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the $ sign in front of the row, so the row number becomes relative.

```
=$J1=TRUE
```

When copied to row 2 it will then refer to row 2, etc.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Not sure how to mark this comment as helpful, as I don't have enough reputation to publicly upvote. But this is the solution I was after, many thanks!

Comment: You asked the question, you can mark the answer. Please take the [tour] to learn how.